# How to find element in ICollection or List using string array?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string array of such type

```
String[] codes = { "a", "b" };
```

And the collection where Thing has property Code.

```
ICollection<Thing>
```

I want to take element from this collection if its code matches any element of array. How can i achieve this, because it seems that there is no method that can do such thing?

Comment: `things.Where(t => codes.Contains(t.Code))`?  I'd also recommend using a `HashSet<string>` instead of an array especially if there can be a lot of codes to check against.

Comment: Thanks, i will try

Comment: By `take element from this collection` do you mean to pick the matches out to a new collection? Or to remove them from the existing collection? You state `there is no method that can do such thing` but there are many methods to do these sorts of things. What have you tried?

Comment: Is this for an EF query?

Comment: Thanks @juharr !) It works perfectly, and thanks for recommendation

Comment: the solution of the first comment was good. I had this problem too and I used that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the first element

```
var firstElement= things.FirstOrDefault(t => codes.Contains(t.Code));
```

or list if it can be several

```
var elements=  things.Where(t => codes.Contains(t.Code)).ToList();
```